# WebAssembly Unity base64 decipher

Tags: unpacking, deobfuscation, functions, websites

When in game (taming.io) going to leaderboard and searching a player id lets say: 1. It renders player data retrieved from here just fine:
https://account.taming.io/player?id=1
If I type this url (get request) well it's not json but looks like base64 string. I downloaded js and wasm code and I wanna find part of project where this base64 string decoding is being handled can anyone suggest what tools to use?